# drawRect method not drawing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, drawrect

I'm using a subclass of UITextField to draw a " m3" string always at the end of my textfield, but something is not working. I know that the method is beeing called because i've tested it using a NSLog, what am I doing wrong?

My class:

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    NSString *strM3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" m³"];

    /// Make a copy of the default paragraph style
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    /// Set line break mode
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
    /// Set text alignment
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:12.0],
                                  NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle};

    [strM3 drawInRect:rect withAttributes:attributes];

}
```

Comment: UITextField has a lot of things drawn ontop of it's self.  Background drawings are going to be covered up by all of those things.  To test this you can programatically remove all subviews and see if your " m3" shows up.  `for(UIView *subview in textField.subviews) [subview removeFromSuperview];`.  I think you are going to have to set a default text, then modify the input text whenever a new character is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITextField has a lot of things drawn ontop of it's self. Background drawings are going to be covered up by all of those things. To test this you can programatically remove all subviews and see if your " m3" shows up.

```
for(UIView *subview in textField.subviews) [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

I think you are going to have to set a default text, then modify the input text whenever a new character is entered.  Set up a UITextViewDelegate and overload the function `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`:

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string {    
  //Do some string manipulation in here to remove the "m3", then add the user's input, then replace the "m3"
}
```

Comment: It appears, but only removing the other subviews, how can I send my subview to the top of the others?

Comment: You can't.  DrawRect tries to draw things on the very bottom layer of a view's hierarchy.  UITextView has built in subviews that overlay every pixel of the view, so the very bottom of the view hierarchy does not show through anywhere.  The only way you are going to get what you want is to make a custom UITextView from scratch, remove apple built in subviews, or modify the textfield string on every user input.

Comment: I've tried to modify on every user imput, but he couldn't use the backspace button, is it normal?

Comment: The backspace button is likely trying to delete the "3", then you just replace it.  You will have to take that into account.  You could always just put a label directly to the right of this field with the "m3" units.  That is a common practice (have the units displayed outside of the editable text field).